# Analysis Services for SQL Server 2008 R2 Express

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express, windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008-r2

Is it really to add Analysys Services for existing instance of SQL Server 2008 R2 Express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with Advanced Services just includes SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS), not SSAS

Answer (score 0):

SSAS excludes SQL Server Standard and Enterprise